# Linux Mint 17.3 not connecting to the internet when in terminal but able to connect using firefox, and i'm using proxy

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-mint, proxy

I have installed Linux Mint 17.3 Mate on VirtualBox and have added a proxy, 
When using firefox I'm able to load webpages but when I try to run update of the system or to ping it fails ,
The update throws the following error:

> GPG error: http://extra.linuxmint.com rosa InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
>   [image]

Answer (score 2):

For Synaptic Package Manager you need to configure proxy.

Open Synaptic -> Preferences -> Network, and configure your proxy there.

For terminal

Use terminal to open /etc/environment using a text edit app as superuser - e.g. in terminal type sudo gedit /etc/environment     (enter password when asked)

Add the following lines to the text document that appears, replacing myproxy.server.com with your proxy address

```
http_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
https_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
FTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.server.com:8080/
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
```

Save the file, then  navigate to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ and create a new file there named 95proxies and include the following code (remembering to add your own proxy address in place of myproxy.server.com)

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://myproxy.server.com:8080/";
```

Reboot and once you have logged in you will find that your proxy settings are in place for Network Settings, apt-get and Update manager.

Comment: Is there any way to use automatic proxy configuration ?